# CoreData: document won't save after initial save

Tags: cocoa, core-data, osx-lion

I am making a document based application using CoreData. I can create a new document, edit the document, and then save it. The file is created and can be opened. Once opened, the data loads correctly. However, once the initial save has been made, all subsequent saves do nothing. The app does not crash and there are no messages in the console, the file simply does not save any longer. If the file is closed and reopened it reverts to the state it was in after the initial save.

Is there some kind of 'editable' flag that needs to be set? Could it be I am loading the data, but its getting detached from the context? HELP!

**EDIT** It looks like it has something to do with Transformable fields. How do I mark transformables as having changed so they get saved along with everything else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure to do this when making changes to transformable fields:

```
[someObject willChangeValueForKey:@"transformableField"];

// make changes

[someObject didChangeValueForKey:@"transformableField"];
```

Comment: Thank you, I've been looking for quite a while now.